# How to find the distance between two galaxies from ra and dec and redshift

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, astrophysics, distances, redshift

I have ra and dec and corresponding redshift of galaxies. I would like to calculate the distance between two galaxies.

I did like this to find the nearest neighbour galaxies.

Suppose I am trying to find the nearest neighbour of galaxy A(which has RA,DEC)  and the target galaxy has ra1,dec1,

so to find the distance between two galaxy, I did like this

```
dist_sqd= sqrt( (RA-ra1)**2 + (DEC-dec1)**2 ) 
#RA, DEC are in degree
```

Is this the correct way to find the distance.

As there is projection in 2D, Since, I already have redshift, Is there any best way to find the distance between two galaxies properly?

Comment: That won't work, consider two galaxies near the north celestial pole, one with an ra of 0 and one with an ra of 180...

Comment: You mean the angular separation? What has it got to do with the redshifts?

Comment: See also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26899/comoving-distance-between-two-points-ra1-dec1-z1-and-ra2-dec2-z2

Comment: Related: [What is the distance from Alpha Centauri to Barnard's Star?](/q/39595)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are presumably using [Hubble's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) to get the distance to each of the galaxies, the approximate estimate would the "the greater distance ± the smaller distance".

But the geometric solution is useful too. Your strategy appears to be something like:

1. Calculate angular separation $\Theta$ from RA and DEC.
2. By trigonometry, the distance is then $d_{a,b} = \sqrt{d_a^2\sin(\Theta)^2 + (d_b - d_a\cos(\Theta))^2}$

The problem is that you can not calculate the angular separation on a sphere by the Pythagorean formula, instead, you need the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). To keep this post self-contained, that is:

$$\Theta = 2\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac{\phi_2 - \phi_1}{2}\right) + \cos(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2)\sin^2\left(\frac{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}{2}\right)}\right)$$

Where $\phi$ is declination and $\lambda$ is right ascension.

People are also linking [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39595/what-is-the-distance-from-alpha-centauri-to-barnards-star) from the comments, which deals with the problem by converting everything to Cartesian coordinates first, which may or may not be easier for your use case.

Comment: what is this d_a and d_b?

Comment: @astronerd Distance to galaxy A and galaxy B

Comment: Thank you. Is it comoving distance or proper distance?